# Nodemon stuck at restarting due to changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

I am trying to get nodemon working on my computer, but every time I make a change, the terminal gives me a notice that nodemon is restarting, but the changes aren't being implemented in the program.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const PORT = 8085;
app.use(bodyParser.json());
//all my routes here

app.listen(PORT, function(){
    console.log(`Server started on Port ${PORT} ddff`);
});
```

When I make a change in the app.listen console.log:,

```
app.listen(PORT, function(){
    console.log(`Server started on Port ${PORT}`);
});
```

the terminal is stuck here

```
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Server started on Port 8085 ddff
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
```

I have tried using legacy watch, installing node again, and using other tools but none of them seem to work. If anyone can tell me why this is happening and the exact steps to take to fix it that would be very much appreciated. :)

Comment: So it never says "Server started on Port 8085 ddff" again after "[nodemon] restarting due to changes..."?
Also, Is this all the code in your project?

Comment: No, also I would expect it to say Server started on Port 8085 because I took out the "ddff" portion of the console log. And yes this is all the code for my project.